# validation error message will not show at form year

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have such a validation rules, there is an error message generated

```
$validator->add('cc_expires',[
                'checkExpiryDate'=>[
                'rule'=>'checkExpiryDate',
                'provider'=>'table',
                'message'=>__('BS_INVALID_CC_EXPIRY_DATE')]]);
```

but the error message will not generated at this `$this->Form->year()` control

```
echo $this->Form->year('cc_expires', [ 'options' =>  $year_option,'error' =>true]);
```

I have to add

```
 <?php  print_r($order->errors() ['cc_expires'] ['checkExpiryDate'] );?>
```

to print out the error message , which is ugly,

is there anyway for the control `$this->Form->year()` to print out the error message, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually printing errors should be done using the `FormHelper::error()` method, and you can test whether there is an error using `FormHelper::isFieldError()`.

That being said, individual control methods like `year()` do not check for errors, they only render the control. If you want automatic error checking and displaying, then you need to use `FormHelper::control()` (`FormHelper::input()`before CakePHP 3.4), which wraps that task (the `error` option btw is an option of the `control()` method):

```
echo $this->Form->control('cc_expires', [
    'type' => 'year',
    'label' => false,
    'options' => $year_option
]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Displaying and Checking Errors](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#displaying-and-checking-errors)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Creating Form Controls](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-form-controls)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > Form > Options for Control](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#options-for-control)**